# C++ Command-Line Arguments with '=' (Equal) Sign

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

How can I parse a command-line option in C++ if it includes an equal sign? An example would be:

```
./testApp --parameter1=value1
```

I use the following line to check if the argument does exist with:

```
bool cmdOptionExists(char** begin, char** end, const std::string& option)
{
    return std::find(begin, end, option) != end;
}
```

However, if the argument includes an equal sign this will return false for

```
cmdOptionExists(argv, argv+argc, "parameter1");
```

Even printing:

```
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
        printf("Argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
```

does not include any indication of parameter1. Yet, removing the equals sign will print it correctly.

Comment: Thanks all, figured it out now, I've already implemented a solution followed by your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can parse them the same way you can parse anything else.  In your
example, `argv[1]` will probably contain `"--parameter1=value1"`.[1]  So
if you want to break it at the `'='`, use `std::find` to find the `'='`,
and break it.  I'd start by converting it to an `std::string`, but this
isn't really necessary.  For a null terminated string like you find in
`argv[i]`, `argv[i]` is the "begin" iterator, and `argv[i] + strlen(
argv[i] )` is the "end" iterator.

[1] Formally, the standard really doesn't say much about this, since it
all happens before anything in your program is executed.  Practically,
however, the most common systems will allow the program which invokes
your program to pass in pretty much anything—even to `argv[0]`,
which the standard does sort of specify.  And all of the shells or
command processors I know will use white space to break up the command
line into words, in the absense of meta-characters.  (What is considered
a meta-character, and how they are treated, varies greatly.)

Answer (score 5):

The command line options in `argv` are space-delimited. So either you have to detect the `key=value` options yourself or you use a command line parser. I suggest [Boost::Program Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Example:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("foo", po::value<std::string>(), "do bar")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);

std::string foo;

if (vm.count("foo")) {
    foo = vm["foo"].as<std::string>();
} else {
    throw("Foo not set.");
}
```

Comment: So what I understand is "--parameter1=value1" is considered as a whole command-line option, am I right? Then shouldn't I be able to see that whole string when I try to print all the arguments within the for loop above?

Comment: Yes if you search for "`--parameter1=value1`" then you should find an option. but that would also include the two minuses, the key, the `=` sign and the value.